# Why does this GWT code leak memory on ie9 (but not ie8 or ie10)

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, memory-leaks

We have encountered this issue with windows 7, ie9 (but not ie8 or ie10) with gwt 2.5.

We boiled the issue down to the following very small code example, which does no dom manipulation and doesn't do anything with the returned data, it's just an rpc call returning a string called from a timer.

The size of the leak is proportional to the size of the string returned from the Rpc call. returning a really big string can send ie 9 memory usage beyond 1Gb in a few minutes! 32 bit ie peaks at 2Gb for obvious reasons, but 64bit ie9 eats all the memory in the system.

Here's the code:-

```
public class TestLeak implements EntryPoint
{
    /**
     * Create a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side Greeting service.
     */
    private final GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

    private static final int REFRESH_RATE_MS = 100;
    private Timer refreshTimer = null;

    /**
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        refreshTimer = new Timer()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                makeRPCCall();

            }
        };
        refreshTimer.schedule(REFRESH_RATE_MS);
    }

    public void makeRPCCall()
    {
        greetingService.greetServer("Data", new AsyncCallback<String>()
        {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
            {
            }

            public void onSuccess(String result)
            {
                refreshTimer.schedule(REFRESH_RATE_MS);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: How does this code behave in IE9? http://jsfiddle.net/qFWtr/embedded/result/

Comment: The memory climbs a small amount and then drops again so overall it's stable. The code above climbs and never drops back.